# Select only unique values from a table, not using count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

By unique, I mean if there is some value that has a duplicate, **don't show either of them.**

Example:

```
Student    |    College
-----------------------
Jake       |    Harvard
Josh       |    Penn State
Erica      |    Harvard
```

So in this case, the result would be

```
Penn State
```

the query would be something like, schools that only one student goes to.

**I want to do this without using count(*).**

Answer (score 3):

The restriction on not using `count` sounds a bit artificial, but assuming the combination of `student` and `college` is unique, you could compare the maximum and minimum per college and make sure they're the same student:

```
SELECT   college
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY college
HAVING   MIN(student) = MAX(student)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a self left join on the college field and different student and return only those records where there is no match:

```
select t1.college from yourtable t1
left join yourtable t2 on t1.collage=t2.college and t1.student<>t2.student
where t2.college is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAG()` and `LEAD()`, as in:

```
select
    *,
    lag(college) over(order by college) as prev_college
    lead(college) over(order by college) as next_college
  from my_table
  where college <> prev_college or prev_college is null
    and college <> next_college or next_college is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no strict duplicates, you can use `not exists` to see if there is another student in the college:

```
select t.college
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.college = t.college and t2.student <> t.student
                 );
```